# InputText da pagina de login do sistema está autocompletando com valores

Tags: jsf, navegador-de-internet, xhtml, cache

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei no xhtml autocomplete = "off" e também já coloquei

```
<head> <f:facet name="first"> <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>  </f:facet> </head>
```

Nada por enquanto está resolvendo essa questão da caixa de texto de login com valores de outros login isso também está acontecendo com a senha dos usuários quando loga no sistema. Alguém saberia como resolve isso? estou usando jsf 1.2 + richfaces